# Multiple cmd commands using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, cmd

I am attempting to run a series of cmd commands via my vb.net app. My code looks like this:

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k activate instance ntds & ifm & create full c:\audit & quit & quit")
```

The issue is that is seems to only be running the first of these commands (essentially: Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/k ntdsutil)

Does anyone know why this would be happening? I also tried replacing cmd.exe with 'ntdsutil.exe' with no success.

Comment: If you want to execute multiple commands then you need open the command window and redirect the standard input stream, then write multiple lines to that stream.  Check [this](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?381405-Automate-Command-Prompt-Window-(CMD)-Redirect-Output-to-Application-2003-2005) out.

Comment: @jmchilhinney : Actually his current method should work just as fine.

Comment: @taco : For how long is the first process running (ntdsutil)? The others won't run until it has exited.

Comment: @VisualVincent it should take < 1 second.

Comment: @jmcilhinney I have implemented your method however I am having an issue with the final two commands:

SW.Writeline("ifm")
SW.Writeline("create full " & sPath)

It seems to be writing both onto the same line and causing a syntax error (due to ifm create full & sPath not being a valid string). Any ideas?